# Как вывести в консоль в кавычках значение суммы без пробелов?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
const n = 7;
let sum = ' ';
let i = n;
for (let i = ' '; i <= 7; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
console.log('Result: ' + "'" + sum + "'");
```

Result: '  1234567'

Нужно вывести в консоль результат в кавычках без пробела между первой кавычкой и суммой.

Comment: Вот это круто у вас написано `let i = ' '; i <= 7; i++` - от пробела и до 7! Вы не находите это странным? У вас цель - запутать код?

Comment: Тогда что ставить вместо пробела чтобы получить результат '1234567' ?

Comment: @VladSir84, очевидно нужно ставить начальное значение, в данном случае 1

Comment: `console.log(\`Result: "${new Array(7).fill("").map( (e,i) => i + 1 + e ).join("")}"\`);` — в качестве упражнения-извращения)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `String()` для преобразования `i` в строку.

```
let str = "";
for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
str += String(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В блоке инициализации циклу нужно указывать начальное значение. В данном случае это 1. Кроме того, пробел нужно убрать и из переменной-накопителя `sum`, и использовать пустую строку в качестве значения по умолчанию.

Код может принять следующий вид:

```js
const n = 7;
let sum = '';
let i = n;
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
console.log('Result: ' + "'" + sum + "'");
```